# Raspberry Pi 5 (8M) problem updating Bootloader

Tags: boot, raspberrypi, firmware

Just got my Raspberry Pi 5 recently.
Installed Ubuntu 23.1 on USB flash drive 128GB.
Was fast, not a problem.  But I am having lots of instabilities and problem since...

One of them is to update

Important → Internal → Software like Bootloader, EEPROM and firmware.

Trying to update my Sept. 25 2023 Bootloader first → Unable.
Using `sudo raspi-config` →  No success at all.
Accessed the tool, BUT cannot see the Bootloader update to the latest in the possible choices in the Advanced Menu as described.

Then tried `rpi-eeprom-update -a`: No more success except that it says:

> Up To Date.....
> FALSE

My Bootloader is dated Sept 25th 2023...............  AND it says:

> LATEST ....2712 release etc

Can you help please to identify my problems and the correct way of doing those tasks  ^  I think that most of my actual instabilities are caused by outdated internal..software...  Maybe I'm wrong...